# How to change structure of nested/recursive JSON

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I have a JSON Array which looks like this:

```
[
    {id:1, name:"Name1", data1:"x", data2:"x", children:
        [
            {id:2, name:"Name2", data1:"x", data2:"x"},
            {id:3, name:"Name3", data1:"x", data2:"x", children:[...]},
        ]
    },
    {text: ..... },
    ...
]
```

And I need to do a similar JSON Array. I just need every object to have `text` attribute which equals the `name`. And `data` attribute which is a JSON of old attributes except `children`.

It would not be a big problem in Python (it needs some recursion probably) but I can't figure out how to make it work in `JavaScript`

So this would look like:

```
[
    {text:"Name1", data:{id:1, name:"Name1", data1:"x", data2:"x"}, children:
        [
            {text:"Name2", data:{id:2, name:"Name2", data1:"x", data2:"x"}},
            {text:"Name3", data:{id:3, name:"Name3", data1:"x", data2:"x"}, children:[...]},
        ]
    },
    {id:4 ..... },
    ...
]
```

Comment: in short, you should use array.map.. there should be plenty of reference on how to map an array using javascript

Comment: @GlenK I understand but I need it to be recursive because I need to change the structure of children and children of children etc...

Comment: hmm.. I think i would do an array map inside the array map. but obviously you can do recursive as well...

Comment: nevermind, yes, you need a recursive, did not realise that you can have children in the children level as well

Answer (score 0):

@Glen K helped me with his comment. I just used `Array.map` with `mp` recursive helper function.

```
    mp = function (obj) {
        var children = [];
        if (obj.children && obj.children.length) {
            children = obj.children.map(x => mp(x));
        }
        return {text: obj.name, data: obj, children:children}
    };

    new_json = old_json.map(x => mp(x));
```